# Use case diagram - System as an Actor that collect customer information

Tags: uml, use-case

I understand that a system can be an actor and it is usually drawn on the right side of the system boundary.

I saw a sample system use case Actor as Product Database System which the use case is to Update Product Database.

I have a full question which I am stuck on a paragraph stated that "The system should also collect customer information such as their personal information, their buying preferences e.g. price range etc.

I'm not sure if I can create an Actor that point to a use case Collect Customer Information?

Please advise as I could not find much examples that mentioned on System Actors.

Answer (score 1):

Is not usually to have the system like an actor (unless is an external system).

Referring to that sentence... Depending on the source of that information:

- If "the personal information" will be recollected directly from the Costumer, that's the actor.
- If that action is launched as a result of other action, you have to use an `<<include>>` or `<<extension>>` point.
- If the action happens eventually, you can create the "Time" actor.

Answer (score 1):

From UML 2.5 standard:

> An Actor specifies a role played by a user or any other system that
>   interacts with the subject.

So, of course, a system can be an actor. But it seems, this your actor is a part of the subject? So,  show it as a subsystem.

> An Actor can only have Associations to UseCases, Components, and
>   Classes. Furthermore these Associations must be binary.

Association is that line you meant when you want system to point to something. Only beware, associations to Use Cases have no arrows - they would be excessive, navigation is ALWAYS from Actor to Use Case. So, it is not *pointing* to use case, but is *connected* to it.

As you say,

> The system should also collect customer information such as their
>   personal information, their buying preferences e.g. price range etc.

All those things are use cases, that MUST be connected to the actor "Customer".

Your subsystem, if it works with some of these use cases, should appear as a large rectangle, containing these use cases, or a small rectangle, connected with these use cases by the connection "containment"- with crossed circle at the container side.

Internal systems and subsystems do not associate with use cases, they contain them graphically. You are creating the system that fulfills these requirements = use cases.  It is shown as containment. System IS DEFINED by the set of use cases. In some sense it IS that set.

If you would show the deployment on this level, then a server or a client comp could have associations with use cases, for a PC is NOT a set of Use Cases. (But mostly it is better to show deployment on deployment diagram)

Decidedly, Product Database System *contains* the use case Update Product Database. It is not an actor.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cases are so simple...But many people confuse-miss use them...

> "I saw a sample system use case Actor as Product Database System which
>   the use case is to Update Product Database"

The use case decribed above use case is wrong:

> Use Case speaks in terms of Customer Language not Programming Jargon.
>   It gives WHAT should system do Not HOW system will do it.

And

> It should have an primary actor which get benefits or achive a goal
>   by executing the use case. No database has get any benefit from
>   anything.

Use cases are very high level functional requirements. They answer the questions :

> For whom we do this system? What those guys can do with this system?

Let's return your question: You have a requirement

> The system should also collect customer information such as their
>   personal information, their buying preferences e.g. price range etc

This type of requirements are called **Supplementary Requirements**. They do not fit into Use Case Definition.  But they may have connection with Use Cases.

> Many requirements will not be expressed in use-case form. DO NOT WORRY...NOTHING WRONG WITH IT.Just record them in other formats.

And Use Case Diagrams are more popular then use cases. Unfortuanely.

[image: Simple Use Case]

Infact your supplementary requirement introduce another actor to us. Since who will take customer collected data ...[image]

And suppose that your customer decide to use very sophisticated data mining tool and you application just provide data to that tool [ integrate to that tool ]. Since third party software is out of your scope and you will just use it, then another system can be your  secondary actor.

[image]

Or Even : Suppose that you will also  develop Customer Information Analyzer system, you may subdivide your system as Online Shop Module and Customer Info Analyzer Module -two parts- and the at each submodel behave other module as secondary or primary actor.

**UML Standard  and Actor Types** [ Again those boring standards :-) ]

Many guys just use Use Case Diagrams. So their vocabulary is just based on UML Use Case Diagrams.  There are mainly two types of actor in use cases :

- Primary actor
- Supporting actor

**Primary actor** has user goals fulfilled through using services of the
SuD.[system under discussion ] .Why identify? To find user goals, which drive the use cases.

**Supporting actor** provides a service (for example, information) to the SuD.Often a computer system, but could be an organization or person. Why identify? To clarify external interfaces and protocols.

[ From Craig Larman, Applying UML and appaterns] [ Actually he identify three kinds of external actors - 3rd one Offstage actor -, but for me 2 types are good ]

This is a terminology from RUP [ Rational Unified Proccess ] not  from IBM tools. And  generalization between actors is as different thing than actor types. To get more info just 
check the free chapter from Larman's book  [Use Case Primer](http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/downloads/applying_uml/larman-ch6-applying-evolutionary-use-cases.pdf)

Comment: UML standard does not know primary and secondary actors. Are you talking about OML? Or IBM modelling tool? If not, please, try to formulate your thoughts without those terms. Try to use generalization abstraction instead.

Comment: "Actor types" and "generalization" between actors are different things. Priamary and secondary [ supporting ] actors definitions are part of RUP  use case modeling .Check my answer section "UML Standard and Actor Types"

Comment: They are different, who says they not? As for primary/secounadry actors their "definition", they are defined in OML and at other authors, but the definitions are different, sometimes even from one author in different publications. And sorry, your answer is not accepted as an international standard yet. :-)

Comment: Because they are different and are used differently I can advice only to try to use one instead of the other.

Comment: International Standard Answer? :-)  It seems that you are Death By UML Fever .... http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/990000/984495/bell.pdf

Comment: Actor Generalization and Actor types  are for different purposes. So why choose one? I already explanined why we use Actor Types in my answer.

Comment: Well that is the nature of REAL use cases not DIAGRAMS...If you try to write use cases, you will also see there is no standard.And who cares Standards :-)

Comment: 1. the question was tagged by [tag:uml]. I have only tried to help you make an answer more up to the question.

Comment: 2. a. Standards and formal rules are very important - translating your task from one level of formal model to another, or from informal requirements to formal ones, you will surely catch many misunderstandings hiding in your conception. 2.b. Haven't you read the Poya's "How to solve a task?". The tasks are solved by dividing them into well-defined parts. And only a formal model can serve as a well-defined border between subtasks. Without modelling you won't solve anything really complex.

Comment: A) Standards and formal rules are just tools to help us.Modeling is just a tool for thinking: not  for blindly following standards.Do not be servant of standards and rules. B. I am sure that Polya ( RIP :-) ) knew that any real problem solving activity is not linear. And Software development is not definetely. C. In reality UML is not a very formal...D) Many guys attempt to create a very "formal"(!) and "stardized"(!)  methods to build software, they all failed. E. Software development activity is a kind of Complex Adaptive System....

Comment: Yes, diagrams are tools for testing our thoughts. But if you want to test a concept, you can't change the rules WHILE diagraming. Of course, you can change rules before or after it. Rules are changeable, but if you are changing them WHILE applying, you only lie to yourself. The other use of diagrams is the help for thinking, but here they needn't be strict at all.

Comment: It seesm that Polya say the same thing  with Descartes’s four rules for reasoned investigation: 
“... to divide each of the difficulties under examination into as many parts as possible, and as might be necessary for its adequate solution.”

Comment: But this rule alone is quite inadequate. Leibniz complained :“This rule of Descartes is of little use as long as the art of dividing remains unexplained... By dividing 
his problem into unsuitable parts, the inexperienced problem-solver may increase his difficulty.”

Comment: For me so far none of the "formal" methods can able to  to explain this "art of dividing" ...

Comment: Michael Jackson has a nice article about it : [  Simplicity and Complexity in Programs and Systems] http://mcs.open.ac.uk/mj665/Simplicity&Complexity.pdf

Comment: Read Polya himself instead of people who tell about it. The main element of his doctrine is thinking backward - from the target to the source. And he teaches how to do it, not only speaks about it.

Comment: And Jackson (thank you) simply doesn't know Polya. It is hard to make a good work ignoring the best work done on the subject.

Comment: Well, Mathematics and Software Development are two different things. Because later involves a "customer" . And you can be sure Jackson know Polya. Polya is a general-standard-boring reading advice for computer science students like Ian Sommerville Software Engineering book.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed it following the text of the article. Maybe he even knows the names of author and book, but no more...